# Why am I getting "Local variables referenced from an inner class must be final"?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm not even sure if this code will do anything even if it works, but I don't know what to do to get rid of the "Local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final" error message, which shows up on the three lines that start with "fireballRight[i]".

```
Sprite[] fireballRight = new Sprite[50];

public void fireRight() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        new AnimationTimer() {
            public void handle() {      

                fireballRight[i].setImage("puercosloco/fireballright.png");                   

                rightx++;
                fireballRight[i].setPosition(rightx, righty);
                fireballRight[i].render(gc, 80, 55);           
            }
        }.start();     
    }   
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated, google doesn't seem to be helping me for this one.

Comment: Where is `rightx` declared?

Comment: Your loop variable `i` is not final. Copy it to another variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't shown all the code, but I suspect that adding:

```
final int i0 = i;
```

inside your loop and using `i0` instead of `i` as the index for your arrays should fix the error.

Alternatively, as commented by @James_D, you can also add `Sprite sprite = fireballRight[i];` before the anonymous class and use `sprite` inside the `handle` method.

Note that the `final` modifier is optional in this case with Java 8+.

Comment: Or  `final Sprite sprite = fireballRight[i];` instead, which just feels a little more natural to me...

Answer (score 0):

As it says, the var `i` needs to have the `final` prefix.  Change the code to something like this:-

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        final int i2 = i;
        new AnimationTimer()
        {
            public void handle()
            {      
                fireballRight[i2].setImage("puercosloco/fireballright.png"); // Use i2 instead of i.
```

Comment: It turned out to be `i`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the field private and static.

Comment: A) `static` is rarely the correct solution. B) It will not address the issue at hand.